# Update only part of a page on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 divs, one div has an html button that runs at serverside and generates an rdlc report into reportviewer that is in another div on the same page.
After the postback the whole page refreshes and clears the data in the dropdown I already selected before the postback.
Please how can I prevent the value of the drop down and other controls from being cleared after report generation from postback. UpdatePanel didnt work for me
Thank you

Loading data to the select dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$("#assayreport").tableHeadFixer({ 'foot': true });
    "responsive"; true,
        "serverSide"; true,
            "info"; true,
                "stateSave"; true,
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'RhemaServices.asmx/GetJobs',
                        data: '{"jobnumber":"","clientID":"0","status":"2"}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            jobdatavariable = data
                            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                $('<option value="' + item.TotalInvoiceValue + '">' + item.JobNumber + '</option>').appendTo('#jobcard');
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                        }


                    });
});



<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                   <%-- <h3 class="box-title" id="jobidss" style="color: #3C8DBC;">Job Card Details</h3>--%>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label style="color: red;">Select Job Card </label>
                            <div class=".col-xs-3">
                                <select class="select2  form-control" id="jobcard" name="jobcard" onchange="return getJobNo()">
                                    <option selected="selected"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: nones;">
                            <span style="float: right">
                                <button id="but_add" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-eye" runat="server" onserverclick="LoadData"> Get Invoice</button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

   <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="box box-info">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title" id="jobidS" style="color: #3C8DBC;">Gold Assay Invoice</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body" style="display: nones">
                    <form runat="server">
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rv" runat="server" Height="800px" Width="100%" SizeToReportContent="True" ShowBackButton="False" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False">
                                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                        <asp:HiddenField ID="jobnumber" runat="server" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

C# Code for page load and button click event (LoadData)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }
    protected  void LoadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Invoice.rdlc");
        DataTable dt = GetData();          

        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

        rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        rv.LocalReport.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: can u show c# code of pageload and report calling code of button click

Comment: and how are you binding your dropdown?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the earlier post,Also am using Ajax to load the data into the dropdown control

Answer (score 0):

so you have binded Dropdown by ajax jquery, in this case what happens that each time you post back jquery's `$(document).ready(){}` event fires and your dropdown fills value again and resets its values so for solution what you can do is just bind drop down by code behind on page load Event in c# try below code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       jobcard.DataSource=dtJobCard;//get data in this dtJobCard using DB or from wherever you want to get
       jobcard.DataTextField="JobNumber";
       jobcard.DataValueField="TotalInvoiceValue"; 
       jobcard.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And Make ASP.NET Dropdown control change it like this in aspx code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="jobcard" runat="server">  
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**UPDATE**
if this is a requirements then you can do following things.
store value in hidden field and check if there is any value in hidden field if yes then fill the ddl and set value else do nothing. below is full code.
Change script code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("#assayreport").tableHeadFixer({ 'foot': true });
        "responsive"; true,
            "serverSide"; true,
                "info"; true,
                    "stateSave"; true,
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'RhemaServices.asmx/GetJobs',
                            data: '{"jobnumber":"","clientID":"0","status":"2"}',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                jobdatavariable = data
                                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                    $('<option value="' + item.TotalInvoiceValue + '">' + item.JobNumber + '</option>').appendTo('#jobcard');
                                });
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                            }


                        });
            if($('#jobnumber').val()!="")
             {
                $('#jobcard').val($('#jobnumber').val());
             }
    });
```

Create onchange function
 like this

```
function getJobNo()
{
   $('#jobnumber').val($('#jobcard').val());
}
```

Synthetically i may be wrong but this logic should work.

Comment: Thanks Amit, but my drop down control is an html controls not server side control,its a requirement unfortunately I cant change. I can only use html select control in this case.Thank you